# Log4j2 JMX custom register

Tags: java, jmx, log4j2, mbeans

I want to register Log4j2 loggers at my own MBeanServer. But when I called

```
Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure()
```

method, only logger configs and appenders from property file were registered.
But I want to take result like after using HierarchyDynamicMBean in Log4j.

Is anybody encountered this problem?

Thanks,
Nikita Koval

Answer (score 0):

if you call `Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(MBeanServer)`, MBeans will be registered in the specified MBeanServer for the following objects:

- all LoggerContexts available
- the StatusLogger for each LoggerContext
- the ContextSelector for each LoggerContext
- all LoggerConfigs for each LoggerContext
- all Appenders for each LoggerContext

You mention you are only seeing LoggerConfigs and Appenders. Does that mean that you don't see any LoggerContexts, StatusLoggers and ContextSelectors?

Also, you mention HierarchyDynamicMBean, but I am not sure what it is you want to achieve. If log4j2 had a HierarchyDynamicMBean, what would you do with it? How would you use it?

Comment: I'll explain what I had mentioned. For example I have
A.java with `static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(A.class);`
But I'm seeing only Logger* which are mentioned in my configuration file, but I want to change Logger in `A.java` on the fly. (Of course, I tried to using jmx package in log4j2)